# SQL: How to return specific char to all lines if case expression met true?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i have SQL like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 document,
 article,
 CASE WHEN isQR='Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE ' ' END AS CONTAINQR 
from product
```

It will output this table:

```
 document  | article   | CONTAINQR
-----------|-----------|---------
TA1        | AROVAN    | Y
TA2        | DOLIPRANE | 
TA3        | AMOX      |
```

What i want is: if any article has at least isQR='Y' then it will give all lines 'Y' to alias CONTIANQR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple trick using `MAX() Over()` window aggregate function

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 document,
 article,
 max(CASE WHEN isQR='Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE ' ' END) over() AS CONTAINQR 
from product
```

`'Y'` will be sorted before `' '` in `Max` aggregate

Comment: This works, but it depends on the character set... and then, what if the alternatives were 'Y' and 'N'? or 'T' and 'F'? (or, better yet, 0 and 1?) One would have to think about MAX or MIN in each case, or rely on the accident that 'Y' > (space), 'Y' > 'N', 'T' > 'F', 1 > 0 are all consistent with each other.

Comment: @mathguy isqr contain only 'Y' or 'N'.

Comment: My point was, this solution depends on the "magic fact" that 'Y' comes after ' ' in the character set. What if in a different character set (on another server) their positions are reversed? This solution depends on something specific in the "physical layer" instead of being 100% logically self-contained.

Comment: @mathguy - Dude it is hardcoded in `Then` clause how do you expect `N` or any other character. If there is atleast one 'Y' then everything needs to be `Y` else `''`

Comment: @Prdp - The MAX is taken over values that can be either 'Y' or ' '. And it is there that you rely on `'Y' > (space)`. A "good programming practices" solution shouldn't depend on such things.

Comment: @mathguy - Thats true according to `MAX` aggregate it sorts `'Y'` before empty string so nothing wrong in that

Comment: You only know that because you know that in the ASCII table the space has a lower position than the letters. (Or by trial and error.) That is specific knowledge about the character set, which shouldn't be required in a purely logical solution.

Comment: @mathguy oh thanks for explaining the issue there, didn't quite understand you at first.

Comment: @prdp - Sorry, we may be talking past each other. You do **not** have NULL in the THEN clause; you have a SINGLE SPACE. You would be right if we were talking about NULL, but we aren't!

Comment: @mathguy - Seriously I don't understand why you are this much concerned when empty strings ordered below the `Y` and solution is working

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `case` expressions, like this:

```
select distinct document, article, 
          case when count( case when isQR = 'Y' then 1 end ) over () = 0
               then ' ' else 'Y' end as containqr
from    product
```